# Ubuntu CVE status interpretation, is the package really released?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates, 22.04

I would like to take this CVE as an example:
https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2018-12020
In case of `gnupg2` it says it is released for jammy. 
First of all, what is released means exactly?
I have found [this description](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134269/how-to-read-cve-2016-5696-correctly) but based on this I am not sure what I should see
When I check it on the ubuntu packages page it has an older version:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/gnupg2
https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gnupg2
Also if I use this command then it shows the same: `apt-cache policy gnupg2` (before this I did an update)

I am unsure how I should interpret this, also until now I have not found the right documentation for this and this is why I am turning to the community.

So is the version available in the mentioned CVE for jammy? If it is yes then how?

Comment: It doesn't say `released`. It says `Released (2.2.8-1ubuntu1)`. Examine the [changelog for that package upload](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gnupg2_2.2.8-1ubuntu1/changelog), and read for yourself the CVE mitigation action there (merge from Debian). Use apt to verify that your package is that version or higher.

Comment: It might be clearer if you go on Launchpad and look at when the changelogs for each package mention each CVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your concern (or question) in complete detail, but here's my take on it:

1. The package [`gnupg2`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/gnupg2) is a "transitional package" that simply installs the package `gnupg` (likely after `gnupg2` became default over `gnupg1`).
2. The CVE clearly states that *"GnuPG before 2.2.8 mishandles the original filename during decryption ..."*
3. Since the [`gnupg`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/gnupg) version for Jammy is `2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1`, it's evident that this package isn't affected. This can further be verified when looking at the [CVE](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2018-12020) under `gnupg` and `jammy`, where it simply says "Does not exist".

However, I must admit that I also don't fully understand why Canonical refer to version `2.2.8-1` under `gnupg2` all the way from Ubuntu 18.10 to 23.10.

My guess is that the `gnupg2` package in `Universe` was affected at some point, but that this is no longer the case after `gnupg` switched from version 1 to version 2 between Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04.

I guess my main point is, that you don't need to be too concerned over this particular CVE.

Comment: Thanks, basically I am trying to analyze and handle CVEs. I am using tool which gives a set of packages and the CVE for it. The information is based on the ubuntu's oval.... When I manually check the CVE, I saw the packages but then for the gnupg2 it says released but then I do not see the correct version (this is not what I would expect). I am trying to understand how I can tackle this. I try to find the source of the truth. What you said about the transitional package is valid point which I did not consider. The provided information just a little confusing.

Comment: @Avioder3975 I agree that the information presented on that CVE is not crystal clear. At least the above is my conclusion from it.